# Move_uploaded_file() возвращает false

Tags: файлы, php

```
$file_path = '/img/'.uniqid().$_FILES['file']['name'];
echo $_FILES['file']['size'] ."<br>";
IF (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['name'], $file_path))
echo "yo;"; else echo "nope";
```

---

```
<form action="add.php?add=add" method="post" name="file"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  target="_self">
<center>
<input onclick="imgvs()" type="radio" id="img_rb" name="TYPE" value="IMG" >Картинку
<input  onclick="txvis()" type="radio" id="txt_rb" name="TYPE" value="TXT" >Текст</center> <br><br>

<b>Заголовок:</b><br><input type="text"   name="TITLE" size=120 maxlength=105  formmethod="post">

<textarea id="txa"   class="textarea_class" name="TEXT" cols="92" rows="20" maxlength="10000"  formmethod="post"></textarea> 
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000">
<input id="but" type="file" name=file accept="image/jpeg, image/png,image/gif, image/bmp" class="obzor_butt">
<?php if(($err<>0)or($err<>"")) {echo "<br><font color='red'><b>Ошибка: ".$err."</b></font><br>";}?>
<input type="submit" value="         +         ">

</from>
```

Comment: а что выводится по echo $_FILES['file']['size']? путь /img/ наводит на подозрения, что на самом деле имеется ввиду /path/to/site/img/, хотя, конечно, не обязательно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите что и куда вы перемещаете. $_FILES['file']['name'] - это название файла, а вам нужен путь $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].  и в файл $file_path, я бы посоветовал использовать абсолютный путь, т.е. дополнить $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. Вообще на заметку print_r() оч хорошо выводит содержание массива ;)

Comment: @oldy, теперь пишет 
` move_uploaded_file(/img/530f41bf9492cChrysanthemum.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Z:\home\ord.ru\www\add.php on line 71 `

Comment: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'Z:\tmp\phpDC7F.tmp' to '/img/530f41bf9492cChrysanthemum.jpg' in Z:\home\ord.ru\www\add.php on line

Comment: @ололо, указывайте полный путь в переменной, куда перемещаете. В вашем случае должно быть что-то в виде Z:/home/ord.ru/www/img/, а не просто /img/. И сама папка Z:/home/ord.ru/www/img должна существовать

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [официальной документации](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file):

> Если filename не является загруженным
> файлом, никаких действий не
> предпринимается и move_uploaded_file()
> возвращает FALSE.
>
> Если filename является загруженным
> файлом, но не может быть перемещён по
> каким-либо причинам, никаких действий
> не предпринимается и
> move_uploaded_file() возвращает FALSE.
> Кроме того, отображается
> предупреждение.

Проверьте, существует ли путь, куда вы хотите переместить файлы, есть ли права на запись у процесса. Возможно, в php.ini прописан несуществующий путь для директивы upload_tmp_dir или в него нет прав на запись